# Magento Themes Question

Tags: magento-1.9

We need to have secure themes, with lots of features, good support and free / freqeunt updates. Would you recommend anything? 
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look on [themeforest.net for Magento themes](http://themeforest.net/category/ecommerce/magento?ref=romankazimi). You can sort on rating and read reviews and they offer a lot of well designed themes with amazing features.

Comment: Thanks, Do have any other suggestions?

Comment: How to validate the security of the theme and that it does not add any security vulnerability or back doors  to the store?

Comment: To be sure that you could trust the code, you should check the code yourself :) However I **never** experienced such a security vilnerability where the developer adds a backdoor to a theme